# The ubiquity of "X is a (left exact) localization of a generic X" theorems

Tags: ct.category-theory

Please, look at these statements:

- Every locally finitely presentable category is a localization of a presheaf category $[A^°,Set]$.
- [Giraud] Every Grothendieck topos is a left-exact localization of a presheaf category $[A^°, Set]$.
- [[Gabriel-Popescu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%E2%80%93Popescu_theorem)] Every Grothendieck category is a left exact localization of a module category.
- [[$\triangle$-Gabriel-Popescu](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870810001325)]
  Almost the same, but for triangulated categories.
- [["Homotopy" Gabriel-Popescu](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/stablemodelcats.pdf)] Almost the same, but for stable model categories.

Category Theory often casts the spell that says: "do you see all these theorems? Now look how they become one and the same: ...". Is it possible to do this magic here?

(I could attempt to give you my personal way to answer, but I prefer to wait.)

Comment: You might include also the [$\infty$-Giraud Theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2C1%29-topos#GiraudAxioms). The Schwede-Shipley theorem also has an $\infty$-categorical formulation. I might also include the fact that every presentable $\infty$-category is presented by a Cisinski model structure, or even just by a combinatorial model structure. In another direction, one general theory is found in Borceux and Quinteiro's [theory of enriched sheaves](https://eudml.org/doc/91577); this covers Giraud's theorem and the Gabriel-Popescu theorem, but not the others.

Comment: In order to formulate a general metatheorem, you will need to work in some good framework for "formal category theory". Personally, my inclination would be to use something like [Koudenburg's approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04070) based on virtual double categories.